# Kali Linux Glitched Boot

Tags: linux, boot, kali-linux, gui, tty

I'm having a problem with Kali Linux when it should start the gui, my cursor is constantly flickering. When I switch to tty2 I'm able to login but then I get in the command line. When I do

```
X
```

I end up with a black screen.

What should I do?

Video:
https://youtu.be/laaL2XExsm0

I reported the bug: https://bugs.kali.org/view.php?id=3368

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I haven't looked at it for almost a year because I was busy with other things too. The solution for me was running the following command and installing everything.

```
apt update && apt full-upgrade
```